# Populate Second Dropdown with React Redux Form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-redux-form

I am trying to populate the second dropdown base on the first drop down selections.

I am using React Redux form library (https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form)

Here is my code sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/k38k75ny8v) to see what I am dealing with. I am trying to dispatch an action.change to load the updated set of data base on the first selections.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Cannot run your sandbox code

Comment: This is really cool never really thought about doing this but I thought may perhaps keep the data preserved in local state and when a change occurs to input it causes a state change causing a rerender on state related dom elements.

I could be wrong but not sure how the react redux form is implemented but i imagine it would pick up state change.

Comment: @Umesh - Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: @EvilDr.PorkChop - Interesting I'll give it a shot. Thank you.

Comment: @Dane - I guess you aren't a fan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

1. Setting the initial states that was array of objects objects.
2. Created a action that would fetch the data and grabbed the first drop down value pass it as a param.
3. Then dispatch action.change (from the library) and had it updated its state.

Thanks for everyone that chimed in.

Comment: sounds great Kevin yeah in theory that should work never really implemented else you would have to hook a detection on your own :)

psssh like that actually is the case.